# How to add QGIS Python API Intellisense support in Aptana Studio3/Pydev

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, aptana

I'm developing QGIS plugins using PyDev in Aptana Studio 3 and I would like to know if it's possible to make it aware of the QGIS API and add some "intellisense" functionnalities when programming. For example, I would like to see the available methods of an object when typing the dot "." after it...

UPDATE:
I also see this message:

> module not in pythonpath

When Hovering any QGIS object in code... Is it supposed to show me something more usefull?

[image]

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can for Aptana Studio (and I guess PyDev is the same):

[image]

I start Aptana with this script:

```
@ECHO OFF
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\python
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Aptana Studio 3\studio3.bat" %*
```

In order for it to find my OSGeo4W Python, PyQt4, pyqgis libs.

QGIS Dev (soon to be 2.0) ships with pregenerated API files that Aptana use (See image 1):

[image]

This is what my PYTHONPATH screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very descriptive answer... The code completion is now working great. The only issue left is the messages: xxxobject Found at:"module not in pythonpath" that appear in popup when I hover an QGIS object in code... Is it normal behavior (check my updated question for more detail)?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my PYTHONPATH setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any warnings from pydev when you import the QGIS modules? If not, you have as much code completion as you're going to get.  This is one of the downsides of a dynamic language like python.

There's a way to force completions, but it's not trivial:  http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-PredefinedCompletions

Answer (score 0):

I found useful this little [tutorial](http://blog.vitu.ch/01082013-1452/develop-qgis-python-plugins-using-eclipse-pydev):

I'm on debian.